# Two seperate Xboxes both having disc problems

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-ghosts

We had an Xbox 360 S 4GB, got some XBLG for Christmas for my siblings to play on while they were in down, but it kept doing this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5llriifmgnxxnc9/DSC_0141.mp4

The disc drive, at any given time, completely random, will start triggering, making that 'beep' the 360 makes when it ejects a disc. It stutters and shakes, sometimes just for a few seconds, other times until I unplug the console.

**Side note: while I was typing this, I had to get up and unplug the 360, because the disc tray kept waking itself up from sleep. Again, sometimes it does this, sometimes it doesn't, the only way to really stop it is unplug it.**

So, I get on Craigslist and get a **new** Xbox 360 S, 320GB, new cables: everything's new. Plug it in, hook it up, and the same thing's happening within a few minutes.

I'm in a new apartment, so on relatively new wiring - regardless, I tried a slew of things. Unplugging things, i.e. the Apple TV, using it on a new circuit, new outlet, different extension cord, no extension cord, different game, installing the game to the HDD (still requires the disc, what century am I in?) And absolutely nothing I tried changed anything.

**Let's establish: The exact same issue happens on two completely different consoles, with different cables.**

Eventually I got desperate enough to get on Microsoft Live Chat - he had no idea what was going on, had me wipe the Cache, uninstall all user profiles, uninstall and reinstall, the whole nine yards. Eventually realized he couldn't do much of anything and told me to take the hard drives out of each respective Xbox and let them sit it out.

**Has anyone else had this problem, ever?**

Is it power fluctuations? TV feedback? Radio frequency interference? I have searched and searched for any documentation, and have found nothing.

Comment: As these are (presumably?) brand new consoles, they should still be under manufacturer's warranty. Have you considered returning them to Microsoft for repair?

Comment: Stickers still on it? Sweat? Air conditioner on?

Comment: are the disc trays trigger with a button like in the white xbox? or with a sensor like in the newer (last version I believe) black xboxes 360?

Comment: Clean the sensor eject button and use the controller to eject the disk.

Comment: a few possibilities could exist that I can think of 1 do you have a remote in the house that is designed to work with xboxes? could it be wedged in a couch cushion or similar and when you move just right it is triggering it to open? the same could be applied if maybe you have a neighboring house real close,maybe they have such a remote and are curious why sometimes it is not wanting to work for them...meanwhile they are mashing on the eject button and seeing a paired light not realizing it connected to your system instead

Comment: another possibility though less likely,my family has had terrible luck with electronics going heywire for no apperant reason,especially washing machines....eventually we discoverd that the water in the house was highly sulfuric and the sufuric gas in the air was eating away at the electronics in the house and causing these problems...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your issue has already been resolved, but I will give my personal experience anyway. I have actually seen this with many an Xbox. My friend just recently purchased an Xbox from, well, Craigslist and has this same issue. We have tried the Xbox at my house as well as his and it still doesn't work. I had a different friend that had the same thing happen to his Xbox overtime.

With that in mind, the only conclusion I would deduce from your situation is that you just had plain bad luck. I would most definitely say that it is an Xbox problem rather than the wiring in your apartment or a different reason.